# Make a second date picker for an input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker that I create with the following code.

```
$('.myClass').find('input').datepicker({showOn: 'button',
            buttonText: 'Date'});
```

if the user checks a checkbox I want to change the options of that datepicker. I tried to do the following but I am not having any luck.

```
$('.myClass').datepicker('destroy');
//I didnt have this line intially but was reading it may be necessary
$('.myClass').removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id');;
$('.myClass').find('input').datepicker({showOn: 'button',
            buttonText: 'Date', firstDay: 1, showWeek: true});
```

Comment: Why not just change the options via `.datepicker( "option" , options )`? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't pass in the modifications to your datepicker options object on change based on whether the box is checked? Normally I wouldn't suggest destroying and recreating the datepicker unless you really needed to. The datepicker widget allows you to change options dynamically, like so:

```
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $(".myClass").datepicker("option", this.checked ?
        {
            firstDay: 1,
            showWeek: true
        } :
        {
            firstDay: 0,
            showWeek: false
        });
});
```

Comment: Yes. I realize now I was going about it the wrong way with attempted recreation instead of editing.